# Induced current in a superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, superconductivity, magnetostatics

I was recently solving a problem from Jaan Kalda's handouts;

Parallel to and at a distance $h$ above the surface of an infinite planar superconductor is an
infinitely long straight wire with current $I$ running though it. Determine the force acting on a unit length
of this wire.

In this problem, I have an intuitive feeling that perhaps some kind of induced current develops (similar to how induced charges develop when a line charge is brought in the vicinity of a metallic-charged infinite sheet) but on second thought, that does not make sense since usually in superconductor problems, I am required to ensure that there is no electric field at the surface of the superconductor or that no current flows through it.
So, I don't know how to explain this at all and I'm not at all certain if I'm thinking in the right direction.

Moreover, my primary question is what property of superconductors comes into play here? I know that superconductors behave as normal conductors after a certain "critical magnetic field" is produced in the region but otherwise under very low temperatures, they do not let any magnetic field permeate them (Meissner effect), but I know little else beyond that. Can anyone help me determine the key property of superconductors being used herein?

Comment: No $B$-field can penetrate.
(So ${\bf B}$ must be parallel to the surface, so an image wire with the appropriate current to obtain that would be a way to solve it.)